# Laravel both of created_at and updated_at update to same value in update action

Tags: php, laravel

in laravel after update existing data with other database's column information both of `created_at` and `updated_at` are updating to same value.

My Form:

```
{!! Form::model($user_data,array('url' => array('manageUsers', $user_data->id), 'files' => true,'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'validate','id'=>'xfrm_submit')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('id',$user_data->id) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label( 'acceptor_name','Acceptor Name:' ) !!}
    <span style="color:#ff0000;padding: 0 2px 2px 0">*</span>
    <input id="acceptor_name"
           name="acceptor_name"
           type="text"
           value="{{$user_data->acceptor_name}}">
</div>
</form>
```

My Controller `update` action :

```
public function update(StoreUserManagment $request)
    {
        $user_data  = User::find($request->input('id'));
        $user_data->acceptor_name =$request->input('acceptor_name');
        $user_data->save();
        return redirect('manageUsers');

    }
```

Migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', '20');
        $table->string('family', '25');
        $table->string('username', '15')->unique();
        $table->string('password', '64');
        $table->string('token', '50');
        $table->string('email', '20')->unique();
        $table->string('remember_token', '100');
        $table->string('image_file_name', '50');
        $table->string('mobile_number', '13');
        $table->tinyInteger('status');
        $table->text('account_state_note');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are using migrations, can you show how you created the table?

Comment: @Abhishek yes, post updated, please review that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11518

I solved this using `->nullableTimestamps()` instead of `->timestamps()`

You can try this,may be it will work

Answer (score 3):

This is not Laravel or PHP issue but this is MySQL 5.7 change (you probably use MySQL 5.7). To solve this you need to allow timestamp to be nullable so MySQL won't fill those with current timestamps, so in Laravel you need to use `nullableTimestamps()` instead of `timestamps()` or use `timestamp()->nullable()` for single timestamp field.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `save()` instead of `update()` in the controller